# hm-tap expression not like ng-click

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hammer.js

I am using the angular-hammerjs library (https://github.com/kievechua/angular-hammer) with my phonegap application. I cannot get hm-tap to have the same expression as ng-click. To explain:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="counter = counter + 1">Click me</a>
<h2>{{counter}}</h2>
```

Works perfectly to increase the counter, but

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" hm-tap="counter = counter + 1">Click me</a>
<h2>{{counter}}</h2>
```

doesn't work. Anyone have a solution or an idea to this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems hm-tap needs to call a scope function and not update a scope variable directly.  I don't know why, but that's my observation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is still relevant, but your example does work for me with [ryan mullin's angular-hammer](https://github.com/RyanMullins/angular-hammer/blob/master/angular.hammer.js) fork. However, the following type error:

```
TypeError: fn.call is not a function
```

is thrown every time the button is clicked.

I was also surprised that if you provide a function name without brackets, the function will still be called. Whereas with ng-click you would need to add the brackets, as in:

```
ng-click="myFunction()"
```

For the hm-tap directive the following will also work:

```
hm-tap="myFunction"
```

Comment: We have also dealt with this at my work. It seems that using `hm-tap` without parentheses is fine, but takes longer because either `angular` or `angular-hammer` has to parse through everything.